# How to programmatically use an application pool as a template

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6

In IIS6, when creating a new application pool through the IIS6 Manager you have the option of using an existing application pool as a template. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I've been looking at Directory Services on Windows 2003 Enterprise Server. I have code to programmatically create the website, application pool, and virtual directory, but unable to determine how to address this issue.

EDIT:
This is what I came up with to copy the properties and settings from one application pool to another in C# using the System.DirectoryServices namespace. This example uses the Default Application Pool as the template. I thought I would share it in the event someone else needed to do this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry DefaultAppPool = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/DefaultAppPool");

DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools");

DirectoryEntry newAppPool = root.Invoke("Create", "IIsApplicationPool", "FOO") as DirectoryEntry;

newAppPool.CommitChanges();

DefaultAppPool.CopyTo(newAppPool);
```

Comment: I've not done this with C#, but Powershell has the command `New-WebAppPool` that has no parameter for using a template; also, once the app pool is created the template is no longer referenced. I therefore suspect that the 'Use existing as template' is a function of IIS Manager's UI itself, not something built into the API.

Comment: I was able to figure this out using C# with the following code. I thought I would share it in the event someone else needed to do this: 
[code]

Comment: That's just come up as the word "[code]", was that deliberate?

Comment: Yes and no,  I was trying to include the code I am using to show what I'm doing and I was thinking I could include it using bbcode in the comments.